# Centering background

Tags: html, css, background

so I have background, which width is 1920px, and I'm trying to center it when the resolution is smaller than 1920x1080(1200).

At the moment image shows up, but it isn't in the center of screen.

My code:

```
header {
  background-image: url("images/header.jpg") ;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 306px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Link about **[background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)**

```
header {
  background-image: url("images/header.jpg") ;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 306px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center; //add
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to crop the background just use

```
background-position: top center
```

this will ensure a centered alignment of the background along the x-axis and and a top-alignment along the y-axis

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 html { 
  background: url(images/#.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This will allow your image to be centered on whatever screen it is viewed on!